# A good sentence for specifying "without considering something" formally

Tags: phrases, sentence, conditionals

Suppose that someone has done something valuable, but in doing that he has made some kind of cheating.

I want to say that if we ignore the cheating, the work is valuable itself.

What is an appropriate sentence for that in a very formal language?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Notwithstanding indiscretions in methodology, the value of the work is irrefutable.**

That's formal

and stuffy

with a readability score at the college grad level.

Notwithstanding that, B.S. still sometimes baffles brains. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The way you worded it in your question is fine.

An emphatic locution would be "in and of itself" — *The work is valuable in and of itself.*

A single-word modifier would be "intrinsically" — *The work is intrinsically valuable.*

Answer (score 1):

"Regardless the way it has been done/executed/applied/conducted"

Comment: regardless *of*

Answer (score 1):

- Leaving aside the method, the results are valuable.
- Despite the means, the results are valuable.

Answer (score 1):

"Notwithstanding his unethical methods,..."

Answer (score 0):

***Modulo*** *any cheating.*

It's a term borrowed from mathematics, but it is in pretty common use these days, at least in some circles.  It means precisely what you requested: ignoring/disregarding the influence of.